# How to access external list data from the SharePoint Add-in?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I need to create a SharePoint Online Add-in (app) which access external list data. However no success till now - I allways receive **ServerUnauthorizedAccessException** .

Here are my setup:

I've created external list using data from Azure SQL.

Permissions in AppManifest.xml:

```
  <AppPermissionRequests>
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/bcs/connection" Right="Read" />
  </AppPermissionRequests>
```

Created External BCS connection and selected it during app install.

My code trying to access list data:

```
  Entity entity = clientContext.Web.GetEntity(entityNamespace, entityName);
  LobSystem lobSystem = entity.GetLobSystem();
  LobSystemInstanceCollection lobSystemInstanceCollection = lobSystem.GetLobSystemInstances();
  clientContext.Load(lobSystemInstanceCollection);
  clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
  LobSystemInstance lobSystemInstance = lobSystemInstanceCollection[0];
  // get the filters for given name of method instance

  FilterCollection fCollection = entity.GetFilters(readListInstanceName);
  // get the Line of Business data
  EntityInstanceCollection result = entity.FindFiltered(fCollection, readListInstanceName, lobSystemInstance);
  clientContext.Load(result);
  clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

However at this point I receive exception:

**Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerUnauthorizedAccessException: Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.**

At the moment I have bunch of unaswered questions:

Could anybody show any sample how Add-in can read data from an external list?

Should Add-in somehow explicitly use External BCS connection?

Is there any way to find out to what is denied here - access to the connection string, access to the SQL ..?

Any other ideas?

Comment: Have you found a resolution to this?  I'm having the same issue.